# How do I parse data from AppleScript executed in Swift app?

Tags: swift, macos, applescript

I'm using OSAKit which is almost identical to using NSAppleScript. I'm running a script from my Swift app and I want to parse the data that is returned, but specifically the AppleScript "record" that is returned. "record" of course being their name for a dictionary or key value collection.

I am able to parse simple bools and strings returned using stringValue and booleanValue. However I cannot figure out the more complex return values such as "lists" and "records".

AppleScript Code:

```
on excecute()
    set returnRecord to {isAlive:true, name:"Bob Belcher", age:40, kids:{"Tina", "Gene", "Louise"}}
    return returnRecord
end excecute
```

Swift Code:

```
if let scriptPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "theScriptToRun", withExtension: "scpt"){
    if let scriptObject = OSAScript(contentsOf: scriptPath, error: nil){
        var error:NSDictionary?
        if let output = scriptObject.executeHandler(withName: "excecute", arguments: [], error: &error){
            debugPrint(output)
            // How do I access the values in the "record" here?
            // see below for output of debugPrint
        }else if (error != nil){
            debugPrint(error!)
        }
    }
}
```

debug output

```
<NSAppleEventDescriptor: { 'usrf':[ 'utxt'("isOpen"), 'true'("true"), 'utxt'("currentDocument"), 'utxt'(""), 'utxt'("allDocuments"), [ [ 'utxt'("5175457_300-p1649981-s6128261-i13876154-v19392759-c[32f86]-p[d]-M.jpg") ] ] ] }>
```

Their documentation has something called forKeyword but it takes in something called AEKeyword which is a 4 letter code. I cannot figure this out. Relevant docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsappleeventdescriptor

Comment: I recommend to use the built-in AppleScriptObjC. You need only a small ObjC bridge file, then you can execute scripts from Swift. The AppleScript collection types `list` and `record` are implicitly bridged to `Array` and `Dictionary`. An extra benefit is that you can mix AppleScript and ObjC code on the AppleScript side.

Comment: If you really want to do it yourself, the `AppData` class from [SwiftAutomation](https://bitbucket.org/hhas/swiftae/src/) provides direct AE<->Swift bridging so feel free to lift what you need from that. (I've no plans to develop or support that code any further, so will public domain it shortly.) Or, if you're only running embedded scripts, not user-supplied ones then, as vadian says, use ASOC, which is officially "supported" by Apple and provides most of the bridging for you (you'll need to define protocols/headers so your own code knows what classes and methods your ASOC code defines).